# How to show something from database in the drop down on the load of view page using Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, post

Hi i developed all this functionality using core PHP everything is working well. Now the main thing is i want this one in CodeIgniter so i am trying to shift the core PHP code into CI code.

My aim is in a view page of codeIgniter there will be two date fields called start date and end date. On the page load which will contain current dates in both fields. These two date fields will be used to select a date range. Those two dates will be shown using below code in the view page called view.php

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
$(function() {
    $( "#start_date" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#end_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    }).datepicker("setDate", "0");
    $( "#end_date" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 3,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#start_date" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    }).datepicker("setDate", "0");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <div id="dates">
        <label for="start_date">start date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="start_date" name="start_date" />
        <label for="end_date">end date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="end_date" name="end_date" />
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now this view page will be called from this below controller called show.php.

```
<?php if(! defined('BASEPATH') ) exit("NO Direct Script Access Allowed");

class Show extends CI_Controller{

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
                    $this->load->model('view_model');
            }

            public function view()
            {
                 $this->load->view('view');
            }
}
```

Now we can see two date fields in the view page in a proper CI configurations.I can see up to this. Now i want to send these two date fields to query something in the database, get those and show it in the drop down using Ajax call. So i tried to do it in the following way.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var from_date = $("#start_date").val();
var to_date = $("#end_date").val();

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  url: '<?php echo base_url().'show/get_ros';?>',
  data : { from: from_date , to: to_date },
  success : function(res){
    $('#ro').html(res);
  }
}); 

});
```

The above function is added in the view file and another div tag will be added in the view file to show the results form this Ajax call.

```
<div id="result">
    <select name="ro" id="ro">

    </select>
</div>
```

But before i implement something in model side i am checking whether post call is coming to controller method get_ros or not but it's not coming. I am in middle without knowing how to proceed any one helps it will be great.

Comment: How you know that `data` is not getting back to you from `contoller` (show/get_ros)? I think you just say this because `select` stills blank but... can you please make sure checking your browser console doing some `console.log(res)`? After that, will be good to do some `for` or `map` function in order to `append` the data to the `select` instead of using `html(..)`, if the `res` variable is not `undefined`.

Comment: can u give some example .......i am new to ajax.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first you need to make a new function in your controller which will recieve the data from the ajax call

```
<?php
    public function get_ros(){
        if($this->input->post(null)){
            //print_r($this->input->post());die;              #just to check if the values alerted in the success function of the ajax call or else commnet this line.
            echo $result = $this->your_model->your_function();  #call the model function to return the result in HTML markup or whatever   
        }else{
            echo '0';                                       #if no post submission is found just echo 0
        }
    }
?>
```

In your model you will get the post variables:

```
<?php
    function your_function(){
        ### dump the post variables into local variables ###
        $from   = $this->input->post('from_date', true);
        $to     = $this->input->post('to_date', true);
        #query your database as you like and "return " the data         
    }
?>
```

Comment: Reply if you need any more help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use double quotes `"` inside the single quote in the  `ajax url`

```
url: '<?php echo base_url()."show/get_ros";?>',
```

OR

```
url: '<?php echo site_url("show/get_ros");?>',
```

Hope it makes sense

Also you should wrap the `ajax` call on focus out of the second date fields

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#end_date").focusout(function(){

var from_date = $("#start_date").val();
var to_date = $("#end_date").val();

$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
async: false,
url: '<?php echo base_url()."show/get_ros";?>',
data : { from: from_date , to: to_date },
success : function(res){
$('#ro').html(res);
}
}); 
});
});
```

Comment: there will be no focus out or in here. On the page load it should take those two dates as current dates and neeeds to extract distinct things from  table in database and need to show them in drop down.

Answer (score 0):

few things,

add an errorHandler to your ajax request like

```
error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){console.log('status: '+textStatus+'error: '+errorThrown}});
```

so you can see the response status in your console, if there ain´t no error, log your response

I´m not too much into php but doesn´´t javascript think that " show/get_ros" is a js-variable  ?
so it must be

```
url: '<?php echo base_url()."show/get_ros";?>',
```

and i´m not too much into ajax calls but mustn the data option be an object or String ? so rather

```
data :  "from="+from_date+"&to="+to_date ,
```